# replace string using wildcards php

Tags: php, html, css, summernote

I'm using summernote as text editor and when I add an image it adds to it the text `style= "width: ***px;"` (the `*` are numbers). This causes problems when I change the window size. I want to replace `width: ***px` for `100%` using PHP. Is there any wildcard I can use with `str_ireplace`?

for ex add the image `car.jpg` summernote adds it like:

```
<img src="/images/car.jpg" style= "width:750px;">
```

what i want:

```
<img src="/images/car.jpg" style= "width:100%;">
```

or just remove all the style part.

Comment: If you add `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` in your css stylesheet, then this will overrule the `<img width="..." height="...">` . Another way is gving `img { display: block; height: auto; }` in your css stylesheet.

Comment: Or, in php, use `preg_replace('/(?:img.*)(width|height ?= ?['"].*['"])/', "", $your_html);` to remove width and heidht completely from img elements.

Comment: Summernote is Javascript, and you can't do anything to its output in PHP. I suspect the question you want to ask is how to specify an image height. When you ask that question, please include the Javascript code, not the generated HTML.

Comment: @miken32 If output is stored PHP can be used on it.

Comment: @user3783243 the "output" is on the client web browser. PHP runs on the server.

Comment: @miken32 It is a WYSIWYG so it just converts input to HTML. That HTML can be sent anywhere, and likely is part of a CMS sending it to a DB. Same as `TinyMCE`, `nicedit`, `ckeditor`, etc. PHP can be used to fix it. Likely JS configuration should just be modified though. https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1241 might be a related thread.

Answer (score -1):

`\d+` is any number, (presuming decimals aren't used) use that with `preg_replace`,

The `str_ireplace` can't take wildcards. The `i` modifier can be used to ignore case sensitivity in regexs.

So regex for `preg_replace` would be:

```
style= "width: \d+px;"
```

if spacing varies you could use:

```
style=\h*"width:\h*\d+px;"
```

or

```
style=\h*("|\')width:\h*\d+px;\1
```

if quoting also can vary.

```
preg_replace('/style=\h*("|\')width:\h*\d+px;\1/i', 'style= "width:100%;"', '<img src="/images/car.jpg" style= "width:750px;">');
```

`()` is a grouping, it is the first group, and is accessible in regex as a backreference (`\1`). The `\h` is a horizontal whitespace (tab or space). The `*` is a quantifier meaning 0 or more of the character. The `+` is another quantifier meaning one or more.

So `\h*\d+` says there can be any amount of spaces before a number, but a number must be present.

This presumes your with values are always a whole number and pixels. Varying groupings will be needed if units vary or decimals/percents are allowed.

Comment: thank you very much,ill try that, im having some troubles to understand regex but ill keep reading about it

Comment: Any particular part? You can use regex101.com to see how parts are being processed. Here's the first example, https://regex101.com/r/FLsOfX/1/